# How to save the graphics drawn using jsDraw2D as a img?

Tags: javascript

I am using jsDraw2D javascript library to draw diagrams like circle ,rectangle,line etc.in a div. Now u want to save these graphics whatever i have drawn as a div data , so that i can display it whenever i want . Is that possible ?? or as a image to the some directory? Any help is greatly appreciated

```
var canvasDiv=document.getElementById("canvas");
var gr=new jsGraphics(canvasDiv);
var penWidth;
var col;
var pen;
var d1,d2;
setPenColor(true);
var point;
var pointDiv;


canvasDiv.onmousemove = getMouseXY;
canvasDiv.onclick=drawPoint;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var points=new Array();

//Get mouse position
function getMouseXY(e)
{
  if (ie) 
    {
    mouseX = event.clientX + document.body.parentElement.scrollLeft;
    mouseY = event.clientY + document.body.parentElement.scrollTop;
  } else { 
    mouseX = e.pageX
    mouseY = e.pageY
  }  

  if (mouseX < 0){mouseX = 0}
  if (mouseY < 0){mouseY = 0}  

  mouseX =mouseX - canvasDiv.offsetLeft;
  mouseY =mouseY - canvasDiv.offsetTop;

  return true;
}

function setPenColor(noAlert)
{
        col=new jsColor("blue");

        pen=new jsPen(col,1);

    if(!noAlert)
    {
        if(!point)
        {
            alert("Please click at any location on the blank canvas at left side to plot the point!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
function drawPoint() {
  pointDiv = gr.fillRectangle(new jsColor("green"),new jsPoint(mouseX-6,mouseY-6),6,6);
  point = new jsPoint(mouseX-3,mouseY-3);
}
```

etc.